# python re.search matches too much

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

text = '"dimensionsDisplay" : ["Size","Color"], '
r = '"dimensionsDisplay" :(.*)?,'
s = re.search(r,text)
print s.group(1)
```

the output is :

```
' ["Size","Color"]'
```

Although it is the answer what I want , but I think it's should be:

```
' ["Size",'
```

I am puzzled about this. Is there anybody tell my why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r = '"dimensionsDisplay" :(.*?),'
```

You need to make your quantifier `non greedy`.`?` after `(.*)` makes it optional.But it will consume till the last `,` as it is greedy

Comment: @vks: If I am busy, please close frequent dupes like this.

Comment: @olivetree123 u need not be sorry...just accept it if it worked for you

Comment: The question *is* a dupe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no it was not a simple case of `?` being missing.It is diff.

Comment: I see. I'd consider it as a typo then. What is bad is that you did not even explain the real problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no its not....i would say it was a problem with understanding

Comment: then it is another dupe of [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP knew the regex and applied it too...but erred in understanding of groups and non greedy....If u know usage of `\K` apply and get wrong result....and den find out dat d way u applied was wrong ...this wont be a dup for me